# Rotating Text and URL dynamically

Tags: jquery

I have a para element on a page defined as follows:

On page load, I dynamically append text and URL to this element using the following script:

```
$('#nike, #adidas, #cat3').html("<p><strong>Get truly flexible shoes for a long run!</strong><p/><p><a style='color: #b4212f' href='http://example.com/shoes-running-2021' target='_blank'><strong>Get a 20% discount.</strong></a></p>");
```

**This is working good so far.** However I now want to rotate the text and url so that it randomly picks one of the two

```
$('#nike, #adidas, #cat3').html("<p><strong>Get truly flexible shoes for a long run!</strong><p/><p><a style='color: #b4212f' href='http://example.com/shoes-running-2021' target='_blank'><strong>Get a 20% discount.</strong></a></p>");
```

OR

```
$('#nike, #adidas, #cat3').html("<p><strong>Get truly stylish shoes for party wear!</strong><p/><p><a style='color: #b4212f' href='http://example.com/partyshoes' target='_blank'><strong>Get a 10% discount.</strong></a></p>");
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's loads of ways to do this. Here's one. Put your options in an array and use a random index to choose one to display.

```js
var options = ["one", "two", "three"];

$(function(){

  $("a").html(options[Math.floor(Math.random() * options.length)]);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Every time you run this script, you'll get a different result below:<br>
Result: <a></a>
```

Comment: This is more elegant than my solution if you just want a static message that doesn't change without refreshing the page. The logic is more compact and able to handle any number of messages from within the array.

Comment: Neat! So in the option do I add both the text and url?

Comment: Yeah just put your entire strings in the array.

Comment: As Oliver pointed out, your solution is very elegant. Thanks David!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a random number generator as below. This is one way of displaying a random message from a list when the page is loaded, but then remains static until the user refreshes the page.

I have created a slightly more advanced process which cycles through the messages every two seconds (you'll probably want to increase this timer). This would be useful if you want to vary the promotional message without the user having to refresh the page.

---

```js
// Get a random number between 0 and 1
r = Math.random();

// If above 0.5 print one message or the other if under 0.5
if (r > 0.5) {

  $('#nike, #adidas, #cat3').html("<p><strong>Get truly flexible shoes for a long run!</strong><p/><p><a style='color: #b4212f' href='http://example.com/shoes-running-2021' target='_blank'><strong>Get a 20% discount.</strong></a></p>");

} else {

  $('#nike, #adidas, #cat3').html("<p><strong>Get truly stylish shoes for party wear!</strong><p/><p><a style='color: #b4212f' href='http://example.com/partyshoes' target='_blank'><strong>Get a 10% discount.</strong></a></p>");

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nike"></div>
<div id="adidas"></div>
<div id="cat3"></div>
```

```js
// Create array from promo messages
var promos = [];

// Add promo messages to array
promos.push("<p><strong>Get truly flexible shoes for a long run!</strong><p/><p><a style='color: #b4212f' href='http://example.com/shoes-running-2021' target='_blank'><strong>Get a 20% discount.</strong></a></p");
promos.push("<p><strong>Get truly stylish shoes for party wear!</strong><p/><p><a style='color: #b4212f' href='http://example.com/partyshoes' target='_blank'><strong>Get a 10% discount.</strong></a></p>");

// Set index for promos
promoIndex = 0;

// Update promos at the start
updatePromos();

// This function updates the divs
function updatePromos() {

// Add one to promoIndex to cycle through
  promoIndex = promoIndex + 1;
  
  // Check if promoIndex is above the length of the array of messages
  if (promoIndex >= promos.length) {
    promoIndex = 0
  }

  // Update message
  $('#nike, #adidas, #cat3').html(promos[promoIndex]);

  // Repeat this every 2 seconds
  setTimeout(function() {
    updatePromos();
  }, 2000);

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="nike"></div>
<div id="adidas"></div>
<div id="cat3"></div>
```

Comment: This looks great.I am going to try this out.